# Knockout.js foreach: but only when comparison is true

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can I control the foreach to ignore certain elements by using a comparison?

What I want for example is something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: entry where (entry.number > 10)">
```

So what I would want it to do is loop through `entry`'s but only execute when that current `entry` has a `number` value of more than 10.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Currently that's not possible with knockout.js, but it's an interesting feature. You should file a bug report/contact the author to consider it for a future version.

**Way 1:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: entry">
     <div data-bind="if: entry.number > 10"></div>
</div>
```

**Way 2:**
Write a custom filter method that gives you an array of elements that match your conditions and use this in your `foreach`.

Comment: I followed **Way 1**, before your answer, as an alternative - guess I'll be sticking to it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I kinda knew that as it's the usual way, but included it anyways :D

Answer (score 18):

try this:

```
   <div data-bind="foreach: editingItem.columns">
         <!-- ko if: Selected-->
         <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
          <input type="text"/>
             <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Hi @JustMe, good answer I didn't spot the <!-- ko if: Selected--> at first, until I did some research. It's important to note that the if binding can work inside a comment. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html Also might be a good idea to modify your answer so that it applies specifically to the question e.g. use "entry.number" that way making it easier to see how it applies to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @AlexKey I an new to KnockoutJS and I went trough the tutorials and they are very useful.

Comment: Perfect for filtering table rows.

Answer (score 9):

I think it would be better to use the built in arrayFilter method ( see http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html )

```
viewModel.filteredEntries = ko.computed(function() {

    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.entries(), function(item) {
        return item.number > 10;
    });

}, viewModel);
```

Then you can just databind to the filteredEntries as you would normally

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
<div data-bind="foreach: _.filter(entry(), function(item) { return item.number > 10;})">
```

using underscore.js

Comment: Nice!  Underscore is da-bomb

Comment: As we are already using underscore.js this was easy to implement.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to filter the array, Don't forget to pass "this"

```
<div data-bind="foreach: yourArrayHere.filter(function(entry){return entry.number > 10}, this)">
```