# Knockoutjs: how to filter a foreach binding without using if

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a way to implement the statements below using a custom binding, to eliminate the if-binding:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.customersVM.customers">
    @Html.Partial("_Customer")
    <div data-bind="foreach: $root.ordersVM.orders">
        <!-- ko if: customer() == $parent.id() -->
        @Html.Partial("_Order")
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Or put it in another way: Does someone know **Way 2** in the answer to [Knockout.js foreach: but only when comparison is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869264/knockout-js-foreach-but-only-when-comparison-is-true)?

Comment: try http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html , it's will work for you.

Comment: @Sergio: if has a number of drawbacks, which I'm trying to eliminate. See: [link](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/03/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-1ifwith.html)

Comment: @user1252580: Been there, but it didn't answer my question

Comment: I'm confused on why you would have customers that you are looping through, then the orders are for any customer. Why not get customers and their orders in the same json, then its a non issue?

Comment: @John: The example is of course simplified. It involves separate database tables with separate ViewModels. I'm think a custom binding, say `foreachFiltered`, would be the best answer to my question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I think your best bet on performance would be to take the data from 2 different databases and put them together in the same viewmodel. I'll jot it in the answer section

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about creating another computed or function that does the filtering and that you can iterate over instead of iterating over orders?

HTML

```
<div data-bind="with: filteredCustomers('smith')">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach: customers">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach: filteredOrders(4)">
    <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach: orders">
    <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: function() {customers.push({name:'Smith'});}">Add customer</button>
<button data-bind="click: function() {orders.push({id:4});}">Add order</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var vm = {
    customers: ko.observableArray([
        {name: 'Smith'}, {name: 'Williams'}, {name: 'Brown'}, {name: 'Miller'}
    ]),
    orders: ko.observableArray([
        {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 4}
    ])
};

// return first hit (unique ID)
vm.filteredCustomers = function(name) {
   return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.customers(), function(customer) {
      return (customer.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase());
   });
};

// return all hits
vm.filteredOrders = function(id) {
   return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.orders(), function(order) {
      return (order.id === id);
   });
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Yes, that would normally work (using `ko.utils.arrayFilter`), however the Customer and Orders are from separate ViewModels (the example code is simplified). So where do I put the computed function (In which model) and how can I pass the filter or id?

Comment: I'm not sure about where to place the function, but probably in whichever viewmodel you're currently iterating over. As for passing a parameter, see this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FRzbM/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. Still hoping for a generic `foreachFiltered` binding, but I'm gonna give your solution another try.

Comment: Using Tuan's solution as a starting point I've created an updated fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/nYbpE](http://jsfiddle.net/nYbpE). Most of the time I have an unique ID, so I've used `ko.utils.arrayFirst` for this. I also use `ko.utils.arrayFilter` instead of `map` when multiple results can be returned.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet on performance would be to take the data from 2 different databases and put them together in the same viewmodel. For example, in your viewmodel in javascript, grab the customers first. Then grab the orders. Add an orders property to each customer and add an orders observablearray to it.

Your viewmodel is intended for use by the view. So its best to take the data, however it come sin, and make it work for the view. As you mention, the "if" will likely be a perf issue. Also, if you use a foreach in a function as you suggest in your comment it is needlessly looping through items when the observable arrays change. I prefer to get my viewmodel in order first, then the user interactions are fast.

2 cents :)